# How does simplexml handle elements that are prefixed?

Tags: php, simplexml

in the application simplexml has been converting an rss feed to an object and the elements have been extremely easy to reference. are prefixed elements (eg `<this:that>` )referenced the same way as a non prefixed element(`$item->this`) in the object.

I have found no information in the manual on php.net.

Comment: By prefixed, you mean to say _namespaces_ like `<ns:item>` http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.getnamespaces.php

Comment: Yes, sorry. There was an example beside the eg up there but I don't know where it went.  I don't need to get the namespace I just want to be able to reference the element by name and acquire the value within.

Comment: Here is an example

<report:id>6540668</report:id>
   <report:category>Movies</report:category>
   <report:attributes>
    <report:attribute type="Video Fmt">x264</report:attribute>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite.  When you do a `print_r()` or `var_dump()` of an object representing namespaced XML you'll notice all the namespaced nodes are missing.  There are a few ways to get namespaced nodes.  One way is using [registerXPathNamespace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php) in conjunction with [xpath()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('some/namespaced/xml/file.xml');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('prefix', 'http://Namespace/Uri/Here');
$xml->xpath('//prefix:node'); //get all <prefix:node> XML nodes.
```

Another way is to use [children()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) to get child nodes:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('some/namespaced/xml/file.xml');
$xml->children('prefix', true); //get all nodes with the 'prefix' prefix that are direct descendants of the root node.
$xml->someNode->children('blah', true); //get all nodes with the 'blah' prefix that are direct descendants of <someNode>
```

Comment: Another Question. What happens when i have a situation like so:
<report:attributes>
 <report:attribute type="Video Fmt">x264</report:attribute>
 <report:attribute type="Video Fmt">720p</report:attribute>
 
</report:attributes>
Can i just use

$attr= $report->children('someurl') 

if i have already used someurl to get the childern of the orighionl element for report?

Comment: That sounds like it should work.  I would suggest asking a new question if it doesn't.  Comment formatting isn't conducive to questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [registerXPathNamespace()](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php). You register each namespace then you can use each node like you normally would.

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "like you normally would".  This registers the namespace for use with [xpath()](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php), not with the `->` operator.

Comment: @crashspeeder: You're right, I wasn't thinking. What he's actually looking for is [SimpleXMLElement::children](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) like you said, so yea :)